# Apache Flink: Insufficient number of network buffers

Tags: apache-flink

I created a project of flink-quickstart-java (DarchetypeArtifactId).
There is a example code WordCount.java.

This is a part of original WordCount.java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // set up the execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // get input data
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
            "To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
            "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer",
            "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",
            "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,"
            );
    //DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///home/jypark2/data3.txt");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
            // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

    // execute and print result
    counts.print();

}
```

I wanted to read from text file, 
so I changed this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // set up the execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // get input data

    DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///home/jypark2/data3.txt");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
            // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

    // execute and print result
    counts.print();

}
```

But there is a run-time error.
But I can't solve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE2Dw.jpg)

I tried to change configure with flink-conf.yaml.
I changed

```
taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers
```

and

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots
```

and restarted taskmanager, jobmanger,
local but error message was same.
The configuration on the page localhost:8081 was changed, but
the number of error message dosen't change.

In addition, I ran the example code SocketTextStreamWordCount.java
without any change. But similar error evoked, and the error message said
that Insufficient number of network buffers: required 64, but only 36
available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 2048.

How can I solve this? Help me...